# Executing DB2 Mainframe SP Using EL 6

Tags: c#, db2, enterprise-library

I have a mainframe SP with below parameters

```
 IN "APPLCD            " "SYSIBM  "."CHAR"
  ,
   INOUT "CMCNAREA          " "SYSIBM  "."CHAR"
  ,
   OUT "RETURNCD          " "SYSIBM  "."INTEGER"
  ,
   OUT "MSG               " "SYSIBM  "."CHAR"
```

Using below connection string

```
<add name="name" connectionString="Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};Database=DBName;Hostname=IP;Port=port;Protocol=TCPIP;Uid=uid;Pwd=pwd;" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
```

> I am assuming that parameter types and names not mapped correctly between C# and
>   SP. Can somebody confirm below .NET code as I am going to execute it
>   once I got server access.

```
                var AD1107P_APPCD = command.CreateParameter(); 
                AD1107P_APPCD.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput; 
                **AD1107P_APPCD.DbType = DbType.String;** 
                AD1107P_APPCD.ParameterName = "AD1107P_APPCD"; 
                AD1107P_APPCD.Size = 8; 
                AD1107P_APPCD.Value = samParm; 
                command.Parameters.Add(AD1107P_APPCD); 

                var AD1107P_COMMAREA = command.CreateParameter(); 
                AD1107P_COMMAREA.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput; 
                **AD1107P_COMMAREA.DbType = DbType.String;** 
                AD1107P_COMMAREA.ParameterName = "AD1107P_COMMAREA"; 
                AD1107P_COMMAREA.Size = 200; 
                AD1107P_COMMAREA.Value = "OT"; 
                command.Parameters.Add(AD1107P_COMMAREA); 

                var AD1107P_RC = command.CreateParameter(); 
                AD1107P_RC.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
                **AD1107P_RC.DbType = DbType.Int32;** 
                AD1107P_RC.ParameterName = "AD1107P_RC"; 
                command.Parameters.Add(AD1107P_RC); 
                var AD1107P_MESSAGE = command.CreateParameter(); 
                AD1107P_MESSAGE.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 

                AD1107P_MESSAGE.DbType = DbType.String; 
                AD1107P_MESSAGE.ParameterName = "AD1107P_MESSAGE"; 
                AD1107P_MESSAGE.Size = 128; 
                command.Parameters.Add(AD1107P_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jaish.

On the surface it looks like it's ok (not sure what the asterisks are).

However, if you're using Enterprise library 6 then none of that code is necessary.

You would want to configure your project to use a custom database using the Enterprise Library Configuration editor (in Visual Studio: right-click app.config or web.config/Edit configuration file v6).

Once you have your database provider configured the code would look something like this:

```
var db = new DatabaseProviderFactory().Create("the_name_you_gave_your_connection_string");
using (var cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sp_name"))
{
    db.DiscoverParameters(cmd);

    // Set the parameter values either directly or through an IParameterMapper or an accessor. 
    // Here's an example of setting them directly:
    cmd.Parameters["@P1"].Value = "some value";

    // if you want to retrieve a DataSet:
    using (var ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd))
    {
    // ... do something with the returned data.
    }

    // If you just want to call the stored procedure:
    db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
}
```

Hope this helps,

Mike